# If a particular record is not available then I need to display as zero in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT DATE(login) AS loginDate, COALESCE(COUNT(login),0) AS loginCount    
  FROM LMS_LoginTracking 
 WHERE prism_mem_id = 55308
   AND DATE(login) BETWEEN '2017-01-04T18:30:00.000Z' AND '2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z'
 GROUP BY DATE(login)
```

Output is :

```
LoginDate     LoginCount
2017-01-05     406
2017-01-06     558
2017-01-08      11
2017-01-09     406
```

Here, what I am expecting is 2017-01-07 should be 0 as this date is not available in the data, even though I need the result for that particular date as zero result.

Required output:

```
LoginDate     LoginCount
2017-01-05     406
2017-01-06     558
2017-01-07       0
2017-01-08      11
2017-01-09     406
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot's of different ways in which this can be achieved. The easiest I know is to create a table that stores the dates of interest. Then fill it up with the relevent data. Let's call it work_days

```
CREATE TABLE work_days(
    work_day date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

And then you can use a left join on it as follows

```
SELECT date(login) as loginDate, COALESCE(count(login),0) as loginCount 
FROM work_dates LEFT JOIN LMS_LoginTracking
ON work_dates.work_day = date(LMS_LoginTracking.login) /* edit as appropriate */
WHERE prism_mem_id=55308 AND DATE(login) BETWEEN '2017-01-04T18:30:00.000Z' AND '2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z' group by date(login)
```

You haven't posted your tables so cannot be tested here. Therefor this query may not work in it's exact form. Please edit as appropriate

Comment: Hi, i could not create one more table in the db, Can you please provide me another approach.

Comment: do you mean you don't have create table access? Then you can surely a create a temporary table?

Comment: I have permission to create table, as i need to avoid it becoz its live site. Can we not achieve that without creating the table. If that is much need, then is we need to create the same column names in that new table ?

Comment: "a live site" - so there's some kind of presentation layer?